# Dynamically resizing fonts in reports (html pages to be printed)

Tags: html, css

I got a head line `font-size:40px;` which fits perfectly with around 90% of my reports but is a bit too big for the last 10%

Its easy enough on normal pages where we have the `@media only screen` but what about `@media print`

In a dream world I would do `font-size:auto;` which means: make the font as big as you can without going over the limit or breaking the line etc..

Is there a way to do this, beside a lot of `if (text.length){font=34}` lines?

Comment: What about all those `vw`, `vh`, `vi`, `vb` units? Will they be helpful?

Comment: I dont think so cause they are based on media page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some may consider it cheating, but you can approach this sort of thing using jquery.  The following will dynamically adjust the "font-size" css property of any element having the class "dynamic-font-size".  Sub-elements that set font-size in terms of `%` or `em` will therefore also have fonts that scale with element width.

```
function resizeFonts() {
    $('.dynamic-font-size').each(function () {
        var width = $( this ).width();
        var fontSize = Math.floor(width / 4);
        $( this ).css("font-size", fontSize);
    });
}

$(document).ready(resizeFonts)
$(window).resize(resizeFonts)
```

Comment: Cool function :)